# Dynamic chart using android sdk

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can anyone help me how to draw dynamic chart in android... as I have done the small charts like pia chart and bar chart etc etc...using **achartengine** library provided by google now i want to draw continuous moving chart using that library only is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

I've used AndroidPlot (http://androidplot.com/) successfully in a project for rendering dynamic line charts (2 plots on a single chart).